# Retrieving missing data from within the same table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm importing CSV files with missing data into a MariDB table. I need to find all codes that don't have a corresponding `place = 2`.

```
Table cityX
| id | code | place | value | description | subcode | 
| 1  | 001x |  1    |  6.00 | unique str  |   A     |
| 2  | 002x |  1    |  2.23 | diff string |   B     |
| 3  | 003x |  1    |  2.23 | another str |   B     |
```

Every `code` in the table must have a duplicate row with `place = 1` and `place = 2`

```
| id | code | place | value | description | subcode |
| 1  | 001x |  1    |  6.00 | unique str  |   A     |
| 2  | 001x |  2    |  6.00 | unique str  |   A     |
```

I've used variations of  `select ... except` statements to isolate the codes with varying amount of erroneous fields.

Using `SELECT [code] FROM cityX WHERE place = '1' EXCEPT SELECT [code] FROM cityX where place = '2'`, creating a temporary table and joining the remaining `place`, `value`, `description`, and `subcode` fields to retrieve missing codes. I'm retrieving *most* of the missing records, but am introducing duplicates as well.

How can I properly select and insert rows missing a  `place = 2`

Comment: Except is not a thing in mysql - please confirm you mysql version buy posting the result from select version()

Comment: Posted SQL code claims that you use MS SQL (SQL Server), not MySQL...

Comment: ` version() = 10.4.21-MariaDB-log ` - MariaDB supports EXCEPT / INTERSECT. Since it's a fork of mysql I assumed that is was supported. Now realize that isn't the case, my mistake. @P.Salmon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution avoids EXCEPT which doesn't work in every RDBMS (not sure about mysql)

```
SELECT CODES.code,
       CODE_W_1.place AS place_1,
       CODE_W_2.place AS place_2
FROM   (SELECT code
        FROM   cityx
        GROUP  BY code) AS CODES
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT code,
                               place
                        FROM   cityx
                        WHERE  place = 1
                        GROUP  BY code) AS CODE_W_1
                    ON CODES.code = CODE_W_1.code
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT code,
                               place
                        FROM   cityx
                        WHERE  place = 2
                        GROUP  BY code) AS CODE_W_2
                    ON CODES.code = CODE_W_2.code
WHERE  code_w_1 IS NULL
        OR CODE_W_2.code IS NULL
```

I don't have access to mysql to test this, but I got this from [Rasgo](https://docs.rasgoml.com/rasgo-docs/transforms/all-transforms) which automatically writes SQL.

Comment: Ran and tested, this works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

We can use selects which test whether the other values exists. We can either use the queries alone to check for unmatched values, or in an insert to add the missing values.

> ```
> create table cityX (
>   id int primary key not null auto_increment,
>   code char(5),
>   place int );
> insert into cityX (code, place) values
> ```

('001x',1),('001x',2),('002x',1),('003x',2);

> ```
> select * from cityX
> order by code, place;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | code | place
> -: | :--- | ----:
>  1 | 001x |     1
>  2 | 001x |     2
>  3 | 002x |     1
>  4 | 003x |     2
> ```

> ```
> insert into cityX (code, place)
> select x.code,1 from cityX x
> where place = 2
> and not exists
> (select id from cityX c
> where c.code = x.code
> and place = 1);
> ```

> ```
> insert into cityX (code, place)
> select x.code,2 from cityX x
> where place = 1
> and not exists
> (select id from cityX c
> where c.code = x.code
> and place = 2);
> ```

> ```
> select * from cityX
> order by code, place;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | code | place
> -: | :--- | ----:
>  1 | 001x |     1
>  2 | 001x |     2
>  3 | 002x |     1
>  6 | 002x |     2
>  5 | 003x |     1
>  4 | 003x |     2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=81240e0e0857d54d310be570463511f6)*